# Extracting version number from list of paths with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following strings:

```
/bin/python2.7.5
/bin/python/2.7.5/log/dir
/bin/python2.7.5/src
```

I would like to extract the version in a variable so for the second string I did:

```
if ($str =~ /(.*)\/python\/(.*?)\//) {
    my $version = $2;
}
```

Also for the first one, I can do the following regex:

```
$str =~ /(.*)\/python(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)/;
```

But how can I combine those regexes into one main regular expression so (for example) `$2` will contain the version? Any possible way to make it shorter?

Comment: The original title wasn't describing what you were trying to do, just your approach. I've tried to steer it more towards the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
if ($str =~ /(.*)\/python\/?([^\/]*)/) {
    my $version = $2;
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijeb3f/1)

**Details**

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\/python` - `/python` substring
- `\/?` - 1 or 0 `/` chars
- `([^\/]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `/` char.

Answer (score 1):

For all the provided examples, you can use `([\d.]+)`, i.e.:

```
if ($str =~ /([\d.]+)/) {
    my $version = $1;
}
```

---

[Perl Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QDT)
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/otppLM/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**
[image]